# Renaming an AppHarbor application more than once?

Tags: appharbor

Can AppHarbor applications be renamed more than once?

I've added a new project, then renamed it once successfully. Now I want to rename it for a second time and the change simply won't stick. After changing the name and clicking the update application button in the application settings it displays a message saying settings updated but the name hasn't changed.

Am I doing something stupid? (Apart from not being able to decide on a name!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terribly sorry, this was a bug I introduced yesterday. It should be fixed by the time you're reading this.

Comment: We started with a new app and deleted the old one, so haven't tried it since. Good to know tho! Thanks.